# Footer Tab Sliding DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone know a good tutorial or technique on how to achieve the bottom footer tab as found on the below site?  The "More Resources" tab

http://www.washington.edu/maps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo for you with some JavaScript/CSS/HTML (I made a jsfiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xbak7/2/):

HTML --

```
<div id="bottom_div">
    Why Hello There
    <span id="hidden_span">I wasn't expecting you...</span>
</div>
```

CSS --

```
#bottom_div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -35px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
#hidden_span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

JavaScript --

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bottom_div').bind('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({bottom: 0}, 750, 'easeInExpo');
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({bottom: '-35px'}, 750, 'easeOutBounce');
    });
});
```

Some Notes:

- jQuery animate (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) can be given an easing parameter which can be set to make the animation bounce like the one in your example website. Here is where you get the easing plugin with lots of easing types: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
- The `left` and `margin-left` assignments in CSS are to center the divs.
- The `.stop()` function stops the animation if another animation is called. Effectively making the animation appear smooth is you mouse over and mouse out the div several times very quickly. If you don't set `.stop()` this mouse over/out'ing very quickly will lead to many animations playing in order and the div won't stop moving for a long time.

Comment: Thanks man! Used a variation of this. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

The technique is quite easy - There's a div with absolute positioning, with the bottom position set to the negative value of the footer contents height (-188px in their case). When the button is clicked, it animates the bottom of that element to 0. Looks like they've also put a nice easing effect on it too.

You'll be interested in http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Also, I googled 'jQuery sliding footer' and the first result looks good ( http://return-true.com/2010/04/jquery-pop-up-footer-version-2/ ). I know it's annoying when people tell you to Google stuff, but seriously, it works :p